# Regular Expression match vs replace

Tags: php, regex, multilingual, hashtag

In Php i wish to develop hashtag system with multi-language, For that i will use regular expression mechanism, for hash tag split and replace text with hyperlink.

First phase hash match will work for the given code

```
$str = '#தமிழ் மாதங்களின் #வரலாறு';
preg_match_all('/#[^\s#]*/i', $str, $mat);
```

$mat array has all hash tags in a input string like array([0]-#தமிழ்,[1] -#வரலாறு )

Second phase replace hash tag with hyperlink given empty result for regular expression replace function like below

```
$str = '#தமிழ்,#வரலாறு';
$expression = "/#[^\s#]*/i";        
$string = preg_replace($expression, '<a href="https://www.example.com/hash_tag?tag=$1">$0</a>', $str);
```

my expected result is
[#தமிழ்](https://www.example.com/hash_tag?tag=%E0%AE%A4%E0%AE%AE%E0%AE%BF%E0%AE%B4%E0%AF%8D) மாதங்களின்
[#வரலாறு](https://www.example.com/hash_tag?tag=%E0%AE%B5%E0%AE%B0%E0%AE%B2%E0%AE%BE%E0%AE%B1%E0%AF%81)

how to fix this regular expression replace condition ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the pattern `/#[^\s#]*/i` you don't need the `/i` because the negated character class matches any character except `#` or a whitespace char that includes upper and lower case characters.

In the replacement you use `$0` and `$1` which are the full match and capture group 1. But the pattern currently has no capture group.

If the full match should include the `#` and group 1 without it, you can change the pattern to `#([^\s#]+)` and repeat the character class 1+ times to match at least a character after the `#`

You can omit using `preg_match_all` and use only [preg_replace](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php):

```
echo preg_replace(
    '/#([^\s#]+)/',
    '<a href="https://www.example.com/hash_tag?tag=$1">$0</a>',
    '#தமிழ் மாதங்களின் #வரலாறு'
);
```

Output

```
<a href="https://www.example.com/hash_tag?tag=தமிழ்">#தமிழ்</a> மாதங்களின் <a href="https://www.example.com/hash_tag?tag=வரலாறு">#வரலாறு</a>
```

Comment: i got exact result